# Poor Temporal Raster Performance over REST

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, rest, raster-catalog

When trying to consume temporal rasters (float values) served from ArcGIS Server over a REST endpoint, the results served up are "wonky".  One or two time steps will deliver data as expected but in general, it crashes and returns missing data or inverted values, etc.

If I consume the data in ArcMap directly from SDE, [it behaves correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qURGT.png).  If I consume the data in ArcMap via REST, [it is a crap-shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qUqR.png) on what I'll get back, sometimes missing data.

The data is symbolized using "Classified" with the data broken into 7 categories with zero values excluded.  I am currently in the process of converting to integer-based rasters and also reclassifying to see if the issue is corrected but the end-goal is to put this into a web-viewer that I can also query against to get depth values at the x/y click.

The server environment is as follows:

**Two Separate Servers**...

- Windows 2008 R2 - ArcGIS Server 10.1 SP1
- Windows 2008 R2 - ArcSDE 10.1 SP1 with Microsoft SQL Server 2012 R2

PS: If I consume the raster using stretched symbology, it returns the data as expected although I can't control the color returned by the server after posting to AGS.  I've tried using FGDB's and registered folders but achieved the exact same issues with that setup.

Thoughts?

Comment: Reclassifying to integers and using unique values was able to get me closer but values are still represented wrong after about 100 steps or so.  Data also looks to drop out if you zoom into an area.

Answer (score 2):

Esri just called... Apparently it's a known bug and is fixed at 10.2.1 (which isn't out yet and unknown release date).

It's been grouped with [NIM-062763](http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/role/beta10_1/TklNMDYyNzYz).